# How do you put info in a ModelMap without it appearing in the query string?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If I add an attribute to a ModelMap:

```
    model.addAttribute("abc", 123);
```

and display the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String foo(HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindResult, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("abc", 123);
    return "foo";
}
```

I see this in the browser address bar:

```
http://localhost:6060/foo?abc=123
```

Is it possible to add an attribute to the model without it showing up as query string name-value pairs? (I'm using Spring MVC 3.0)

Comment: What view is `foo` resolving to?  That URL must be from a redirect, in which case the parameter is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the `@ModelAttribute` annotation somewhere in your controller.
see answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163517/how-do-i-prevent-spring-3-0-mvc-modelattribute-variables-from-appearing-in-url).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the request method to POST then model attributes won't show up in the url, they will be mapped to form fields. But request parameters on a url are a good thing, if you make it a Post then your users can't bookmark the url. Web applications that post everything are so 1990s.

Comment: Use POST only if you need to send bigger data in fields or want to hide the information