# Spring @RequestMapping is doubling up in URL upon multiple submits

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring's annotations for the first time and I'm having some issues with the URL doubling up on subsequent hits of `@RequestMapping`. I have the following snippet:

```
@Controller @RequestMapping("/login")
public class Login {
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public Login(LoginService loginService){
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupLogin(){ return "login"; }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/retry")
    public String setupLoginRetry(){ return "login"; }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLogin(@ModelAttribute("userName") String userName, @ModelAttribute("password") String password){
        if (true) return "redirect:login/retry"; //hard-coded for example
        return "redirect:home";
    }
}
```

If I bring up the page and just hit the submit a bunch of times I get the following:

> myApp/login
>
> myApp/login/retry?userName=&password=
>
> myApp/login/login // <-- this fails as it shouldn't be nesting logins

So obviously, I'm doing something wrong. My questions are:

1.) What can I do to prevent the parameters from showing up in the URL when it goes to retry? Edit: Removing this question - [found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163517/how-do-i-prevent-spring-3-0-mvc-modelattribute-variables-from-appearing-in-url).

2.) Why does it start nesting logins and what is the proper way to declare this?

Any thoughts or assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's caused by the fact that you use relative URL as an `action` attribute of the form in the `login` view. Since page containing this form can be displayed in response to different URL, you need to use absolute URLs, something like this:

```
<spring:url var = "loginUrl" value = "/login" />
<form:form action = "${loginUrl}" ...>...</form:form>
```